# How to wrap label and input text in one line and make input text take the remaining space

Tags: html, css

I am trying to wrap label and input text in one line
I want output like this:
   [image]

The input box should take up all the remaining area after label has taken its space. To implement it I am using flex , my html is :

```css
.abc{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
    }
    
    #some-input {
        margin : 10px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 100%;
        height: 20px;
        font-size:15px;
        border: 2px solid #7e7e7e;
        flex-grow : 30;
    }
    
    #label{
        margin : 10px;
        font-size:15px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="abc">
        <div id="label"><b>labelxyz<b></div>
        <input id="some-input" name= ”some-input" placeholder="Enter input"/>
    </div>
```

Still the input text doesn’t take the remaining space. The current output is:
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: display flex dont work only IE10 , IE11 and is not cross-Browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not closing the tags properly, for instance you `<b>` tag is not closed and the `quotes` are not the same everywhere

```css
.abc{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    
}

#some-input {
    margin : 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    font-size:15px;
    border: 2px solid #7e7e7e;
    flex-grow : 30;
}

#label{
    margin : 10px;
    font-size:15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="abc">
    <div id="label"><b>labelxyz</b></div>
    <input id="some-input" name= "some-input" placeholder="Enter input"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are not closing the `<b>` tag thats why your input is not taking up the remaining space. This unclosed tag gets appended as a parent on top of your input and creates this problem.

Here is an updated version with this fixed and in action-

```css
.abc{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
    }
    
    #some-input {
        margin : 10px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 100%;
        height: 20px;
        font-size:15px;
        border: 2px solid #7e7e7e;
        flex-grow : 30;
    }
    
    #label{
        margin : 10px;
        font-size:15px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="abc">
        <div id="label"><b>labelxyz</b></div>
        <input id="some-input" name= ”some-input" placeholder="Enter input"/>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

its error in you html you forgot to complete  tag

```
<div class="abc">
    <div id="label"><b>labelxyz</b></div>
    <input id="some-input" name= ”some-input" placeholder="Enter input"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't duplicate the answers. The same answer given by Shekar and Shubham.